# UISearchBar and dictation support

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uitextinput

I have user interface with `UISearchBar` and I implement the `UISearchBarDelegate`'s `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` to perform the search. I do not have a device with dictation support to test this, so I'm going to speculate here...

On devices with dictation support, I would like to perform the search as soon as the dictation ends, without requiring the user to hit the search button manually.

- Does this work out-of-the-box?
- Or do I need to handle it programmatically?

Since iOS 5.1, there are new methods in `UITextInput` protocol and I could theoretically hook onto `dictationRecordingDidEnd`. Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you would want to use the `dictationRecordingDidEnd` protocol method.  Apple's documentation says this about [dictationRecordingingDidEnd](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInput/dictationRecordingDidEnd):

> Implement this optional method if you want to respond to the
>   completion of the recognition of a dictated phrase.

That said, I have yet to find in Apple's human interface guidelines anything that talks about the expected use of this method.

You may also want to look at [dictationRecongitionFailed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInput/dictationRecordingDidEnd) as well as the [UIDictationPhrase class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDictationPhraseClass/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Can you confirm, that entering a phrase into `UISearchBar` using dictation does not automatically trigger the Search (i.e. `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`) on iPhone 4S?

Comment: Using the built in dictation on my iPad did not automatically trigger a search.

Comment: I can confirm that searchBarSearchButtonClicked is not called automatically after dictation is finished